# Select2 Multiple Selection not captured in Serverside. MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 multi select box and when i select multiple items,it's not capured in server side.

### cshtml

```
 <select class="form-control" name="subject[]" id="idsubject" multiple></select>
```

### JS

```
formData.append("SubjectArr", _subjects) //1,2,3 comes here.
```

### DTO

```
 public List<int> SubjectArr { get; set; }
```

### Serverside

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddTuitionDetails(TuitionDTO tuitionDTO) //Subject array comes as null here. 
    {
    }
```

Comment: formData.append("SubjectArr", _subjects) //1,2,3 comes here.
this is wrong

Comment: @azizsagi how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your select html name attribute to the same name you used in your DTO to automatically bind it on your controller:

From this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="subject[]" id="idsubject" multiple></select>
```

To this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="SubjectArr[]" id="SubjectArr" multiple></select>
```

Take note that I didn't use any javascript here. This will automatically bind on your model that you passed on your HttpPost method as long as the name of your html and your properties on your model match.

Comment: I have changed it but still i'm getting SubjectArr = 0

Comment: Can you edit your post and include all your javascript? So that I can check on my end. It's working on my part so I guess your script is modifying it.